# Pages are calling the wrong codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, code-behind, visual-studio-2003

I have a project I'm working on in a Visual Studio 2003 and SQL Server 2005 environment. Lately I've been having some trouble with the codebehind files for my ASPX web pages. Some pages are referring to codebehind from other pages.

Recently, for example, I copied a page from one of my projects to use it as a starting point (it is for a form with multiple pages), After renaming it, the codebehind and other files followed suit. However after modifying the page to what I needed, I found out that it was still referencing the old codebehind (making references to controls that are no longer there).

I checked the aspx code, and the reference is correctly pointing to the new codebehind. I've tried building and re-building the project several times, resetting the IIS, deleting temp files and modifying the web config. No dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy a page in Visual Studio and rename it, it will automatically change the `Codebehind` attribute in the `<%@ Page` declaration on the `.aspx` markup.

But what it won't do is change the name of the class in the codebehind file, or the class that the `Inherits` attribute on the declaration points to.

Firstly, change the `Inherits` to your new class name - this should automatically change the designer file to use the same class name.

Then change the class definition in the code-behind file.